# Polymer iron-ajax detail.response is null

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm new to Polymer. It looks great. I started using `iron-ajax` component to load some json from file (mocking rest service). The load function is triggered by a Polymer `ready` event. Everything goes the way it should go but `detail.response` object is `null`. I got no error, by Chrome's network consolle I can see a status `200` `GET` request and expected json data as response. Here is my [sandbox](https://github.com/fpezzati/yomoka_client).

Comment: show us some code...

Comment: @Flavio hit the link, there is all the code :)

Comment: I'm wondering if you have fired the ajax request off too early.  What happens if you fire it off in an attached callback? The other possibility is the response isn't properly formatted json.  In Chrome dev tools can you see it parsed into an object in the preview tab under network. with the particular message selected?

Comment: @akc42 you are right. I can see the json data in the response but it was not a valid json one (ObjectId in the document). As I sanitize the data everything works fine. Thanks. Turn your comment in a response if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering if you have fired the ajax request off too early. What happens if you fire it off in an attached callback? The other possibility is the response isn't properly formatted json. In Chrome dev tools can you see it parsed into an object in the preview tab under network. with the particular message selected?